# Create a "choose between " questions with exam class

Tags: sectioning, exam

I want to create an exam that has 2 parts: Part 1 will be some questions that students are force to do, and part 2 will be a choose x questions among y to do.

If it weren't for the score, I could simply use the `\uplevel` to specify so, but if I use `\addpoints` and `\gradetable`, I can't get the score to display as I'd like.

Does anyone knows if you can create something like that with the `exam` class?

Here is a MWE of what does not work:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam} 
\begin{document} 
\gradetable
\newline Questions \ref{d} to \ref{e} are mandatory 
\begin{questions}
\question[20] \label{d} Some question here 
\question[20] Some other question here 
\question[20] Do these parts 
\noaddpoints 
\begin{parts}
\part[10] First 
\part[10] Second 
\end{parts} 
\addpoints
\question[20]\label{e} Do this too 
\uplevel{Choose only one of the next 2 question} 
\question[20] Stuff here 
\question[20] Stuff here
\end{questions} 
\end{document}
```

What I'd like on the grade table is the total to add up to 100, and maybe even break it into 2 sections if that is possible. What I have tried is to add a `\noaddpoints` after the penultimate question, but this gives the last question a score of 0 in the grade table.

Breaking the exam into 2 question environment does not work either.

**Edit** The only thing I've found so far is to put the last question as bonus questions, and then use the `\bonusgradetable` instead, but that feels weird.

Comment: Would you mind adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cgnieder Added something

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I have done this already in an exam I just wrote. I will post my solution in a few minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample of my exam basic structure. I know there is room for improvement but I haven't had much time to deal with it. After consultation with the author the `exam` class, adding:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstquestion}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tbl@#1@firstq}%
  {0}%
  {\csname tbl@#1@firstq\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand{\lastquestion}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tbl@#1@lastq}%
  {0}%
  {\csname tbl@#1@lastq\endcsname}%
}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\newcommand{\numqinrange}[1]{%
  \setcounter{qcounter}{\lastquestion{#1}}%
  \addtocounter{qcounter}{-\firstquestion{#1}}%
  \stepcounter{qcounter}%
  \arabic{qcounter}%
}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

to the preamble enables the user to access the number of questions in a range with the command  `\numqinrange{myrange}`, first with `\firstquestion{myrange}` and last question with `\lastquestion{myrange}`. See the example below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry} % Optional geometry specifications
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz,calc}                       % Optional packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent0pt
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Thanks to the author of the exam class Philip Hirschhorn
% This adds the option to count the number of questions in the range.
% Thus we would use \numqinrange{myrange} to get the number of questions in the range.
% You can also say \firstquestion{myrange} to get the first question and \lastquestion{myrange} to get the last question.

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstquestion}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tbl@#1@firstq}%
  {0}%
  {\csname tbl@#1@firstq\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand{\lastquestion}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tbl@#1@lastq}%
  {0}%
  {\csname tbl@#1@lastq\endcsname}%
}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\newcommand{\numqinrange}[1]{%
  \setcounter{qcounter}{\lastquestion{#1}}%
  \addtocounter{qcounter}{-\firstquestion{#1}}%
  \stepcounter{qcounter}%
  \arabic{qcounter}%
}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{headandfoot}                                      % Used for the header and footer options
\firstpageheadrule                                           % Head rules for fancy page style
\runningheadrule

% Header is optional and may vary depending on your exams.

\firstpageheader{Intermediate Algebra$|$MTH103}{Final Exam}{November 30, 2012}
\runningheader{MTH103}{Final Exam}{\iflastpage{End of exam}{\emph{continued}}}
\firstpagefooter{}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningfooter{}{\iflastpage{AT THIS POINT, GO OVER YOUR WORK}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}

% This command is specific to a question so not really needed here.
\def\Bsqr{%
\lower1ex\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)rectangle(0.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{coverpages}
% Here you can put anything as your cover page. Specifics about your exam.
\lipsum[1-2]

% Defining the grading tables. We use \fullwidth to ensure it acts as an instruction. 
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Structured Questions}}
\begin{flushleft}
%
% Grading table for the structured questions, Part A and Part B range.
\partialgradetable{structuredquestions}[h][questions]
\hfill
\partialgradetable{OptionalPartA}[h][questions] \raisebox{1.5\baselineskip}{\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{Part A}}}
\vskip0.5\baselineskip\hfill
\partialgradetable{OptionalPartB}[h][questions] \raisebox{1.5\baselineskip}{\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{Part B}}}
\end{flushleft}
\vfill
\hrule\vspace{0.125cm}
\centerline{DO NOT TURN THIS PAGE UNTIL YOU ARE TOLD TO DO SO}
\end{coverpages}

% Structured questions section.
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Structured Questions}}
\vskip\baselineskip
% Implementing the \numqinrange{myrange} to count the number of question in the  structured section grading range
This section contains \numqinrange{structuredquestions} question(s) of which \textbf{all} must be answered on your answer sheet.
\begingradingrange{structuredquestions}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part Simplify the following numerical expressions.\label{q1}
    \begin{subparts}
    \subpart[3] $\dfrac{9^{-1}2^3}{3^2}\cdot \dfrac{(-3)^3}{-2^3}$\label{q1a}\vskip\baselineskip
    \subpart[3] $\dfrac{\frac{2}{5}-\left|\frac{5}{3}-\frac{5}{2}\right|}{\frac{2}{5}\div 6\div\left(-\frac{2}{39}\right)}$\label{q1b}\vskip\baselineskip
    \end{subparts}
\part[2] Use the results in (\ref{q1}) above to place the appropriate relational symbol ($<,>,\mbox{ or }=$) to make the following statement true.
    \[ \dfrac{9^{-1}2^3}{3^2}\cdot \dfrac{(-3)^3}{-2^3} \quad \Bsqr \quad \dfrac{\frac{2}{5}-\left|\frac{5}{3}-\frac{5}{2}\right|}{\frac{2}{5}\div 6\div\left(-\frac{2}{39}\right)}\]
\part[4] If the results in (\ref{q1}) are rational numbers, determine their decimal representation and describe it (i.e. state whether it is terminating or recurring.)\label{q3}
\part[2] Using (\ref{q3}.) above, approximate (\ref{q1a}) and (\ref{q1b}) in (\ref{q1}) to 2 s.f. and 2 d.p. respectively.
\end{parts}\vspace{0.25cm}
\endgradingrange{structuredquestions}
\fullwidth{\hrulefill\par\flushright \textbf{Total Points: \pointsonpage{\thepage} points}}
\newpage
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Optional Questions}}
\vskip0.5\baselineskip
\fullwidth{This section contains 2 subsections: Part A and Part B. Choose \textbf{ONE} subsection and answer \textbf{all} questions.}\vskip0.25\baselineskip
\fullwidth{%
\fbox{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-0.79999pt\relax]{%
\rule{0pt}{1cm}\Large%
\newlength{\word}
\settoheight{\word}{\Large\textbf{Part A}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr1cm-2\word\relax}{\textbf{Part A}}}}}
\vskip\baselineskip
\begingradingrange{OptionalPartA}
\question Let $f(x)=2x^3+11x^2-7x-6$
            \begin{parts}
                \part[1] Use the Rational Zeros Theorem to determine the potential rational zeros for $f(x)$.
                \part[3] Hence, factorize completely $f(x)$.
                \part[3] Solve $f(x)=0$.\vskip\baselineskip
            \end{parts}
\endgradingrange{OptionalPartA}
\fullwidth{\hrulefill\par\flushright \textbf{Total Points: \pointsonpage{\thepage} points}}
\newpage
\fullwidth{%
\fbox{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-0.79999pt\relax]{%
\rule{0pt}{1cm}\Large%
%\newlength{\word}
\settoheight{\word}{\Large\textbf{Part B}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr1cm-2\word\relax}{\textbf{Part B}}}}}
\vskip\baselineskip
\begingradingrange{OptionalPartB}
\question[5] Find the \textbf{sum} of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ if $\dfrac{x^3-2x^2+3x+5}{x+2}=ax^2+bx+c+\dfrac{d}{x+2}$.\vskip\baselineskip
\question
    \begin{parts}
    \part[8] Show that $\dfrac{x+3}{x^2-y^2}\div\dfrac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2+xy}-\dfrac{y}{x^2-x-xy+y}=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$
    \part[6] Simplify $3-\dfrac{3}{\raisebox{1.1ex}{$1-$}\left(\raisebox{1.1ex}{$\dfrac{3}{3-\dfrac{\mathstrut 3}{x^2}}$}\right)}$\vskip\baselineskip
    \end{parts}
\endgradingrange{OptionalPartB}
\fullwidth{\hrulefill\par\flushright \textbf{Total Points: \pointsonpage{\thepage} points}}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll have a look as soon as im done teaching my class. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, but couldn't we create a new counter inside each grading range to count the questions?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I would need to look at the source code to determine the counter used for the grading range sections.

Comment: yeah, I jsut wanted to point you on a possible venue. Keep me informed if you find a way. I found this that could be of help: http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/hg/exam/rev/2.4

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien See my update.