# Create a "Choose between" in exam class, follow up question

Tags: exam

This question was considered in an attempt to achieve what I want: [Create a "choose between " questions with exam class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85219/create-a-choose-between-questions-with-exam-class)

Background: I'm a math teacher with (very) mixed ability classes. I would like to be able to add "choose between A or B" (or C) questions to my tests, where A gives less credit than B.

Consider the MWE

- I would like to have only the third question to add to the sum of points.
- It would be nice if the grading table would include all three parts with their points, such that I can fill in the score the student achieved at the question he/she chose.

This MWE is very minimalistic, I honestly have no idea how I'm going to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Choose one of the three following questions
        \begin{parts} % only the third part should add to the total sum of points
            \part[1] Option 1
            \part[2] Option 2
            \part[3] Option 3
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took a quick look on the `exam` manual and I am not sure, that your request can be fulfilled. The `code` design does not provide for such a feature of optional questions and listing the credits selectively in the table; at least, I did not find it in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the `exam` class, you can't do exactly what you want with question parts, because the grading table lists questions and not their component parts. However if you restructure things a bit, I think you can achieve your end (assuming I understand you correctly). Instead of treating these as parts of one question, make them three separate questions and give the instructions to pick one with `\uplevel{}`. In the grading table, you can set the total point count to whatever value you want with `\settabletotalpoints{}`. Does the following do what you want?

Edit: added definitions to calculate the final total automatically

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers]{exam}

\newcounter{mytotal}
\newcommand{\questionintotal}[2]{\addtocounter{mytotal}{#1}\question[#1] #2}
\newcommand{\questionnototal}[2]{\question[#1] #2}

\newcommand{\mygradetable}{
 \settabletotalpoints{\themytotal}
  \gradetable[v][questions]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \uplevel{Choose one of the three following questions}
    \questionnototal{1}{Option 1}
    \questionnototal{2}{Option 2}
    \questionintotal{3}{Option 3}
\end{questions}

\mygradetable

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the alternative is to manually set the total number of points? I had hoped there was some way to avoid the points of alternative A and B to add up to the total amount of points?

Comment: Well, you can keep your own counter and create new commands to either add or ignore the points in the overall total. I've modified the code to show a simple possibility. With more work, you could make things more flexible, but I'm a strong proponent of avoiding unnecessary complications in a solution. How elaborate do you really need to be in running through your point sums?

Comment: Yeah I thought one could do something like `\nonumber` (when numbering equations) when wanting to avoid adding the numbers to the total.